# Python scrapy SitemapSpider callbacks not being called

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I read the documentation on the SitemapSpider class over here: https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#sitemapspider

Here's my code:

```
class CurrentHarvestSpider(scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider):
    name = "newegg"
    allowed_domains = ["newegg.com"]
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml']
    # if I comment this out, then the parse function should be called by default for every link, but it doesn't
    sitemap_rules = [('/Product', 'parse_product_url'), ('product','parse_product_url')]
    sitemap_follow = ['/newegg_sitemap_product', '/Product']

    def parse(self, response):
        with open("/home/dan/debug/newegg_crawler.log", "a") as log:
        log.write("logging from parse " + response.url)
        self.this_function_does_not_exist()
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.some_callback)

    def some_callback(self, response):
        with open("/home/dan/debug/newegg_crawler.log", "a") as log:
            log.write("logging from some_callback " + response.url)
        self.this_function_does_not_exist()

    def parse_product_url(self, response):
        with open("/home/dan/debug/newegg_crawler.log ", "a") as log:
            log.write("logging from parse_product_url" + response.url)
        self.this_function_does_not_exist()
```

This can be run successfully with scrapy installed.
Run `pip install scrapy` to get scrapy and execute with `scrapy crawl newegg` from the working directory.

My question is, why aren't any of  these callbacks being called?  The documentation claims that the callback defined in `sitemap_rules` should be called.  If I comment it out, then `parse()` should be called by default but it still doesn't get called. Are the docs just 100% wrong?  I'm checking this log file that I setup, and nothing is being written.  I've even set the permissions on the file to 777.  Also, I'm calling a non existent function which should cause an error to prove that the functions are not being called, but no error occurs.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `loc` in the newegg sitemap looks like it contains compressed files `gz`. Could you update your question with the command line log?

Comment: fyi, I opened an issue on scrapy: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your spider, this is what I get on the console:

```
$ scrapy runspider op.py 
2016-11-09 21:34:51 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-11-09 21:34:51 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-09 21:34:51 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-09 21:34:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-11-09 21:34:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml> (referer: None)
2016-11-09 21:34:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.newegg.com/Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_product01.xml.gz> (referer: http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml)
2016-11-09 21:34:53 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.newegg.com/Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_product01.xml.gz> (referer: http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py", line 44, in _parse_sitemap
    s = Sitemap(body)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy12/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/sitemap.py", line 17, in __init__
    rt = self._root.tag
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

You've probably noticed the `AttributeError` exception.
So scrapy is saying it has trouble parsing the sitemap response body.

And if scrapy cannot understand the sitemap content, it cannot parse content as XML, hence cannot follow any `<loc>` URL and will therefore not call any callback since it found nothing.

So you've actually found a bug in scrapy (thanks for reporting): https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2389

As for the bug itself,

The different sub-sitemaps, e.g. http://www.newegg.com/Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_store01.xml.gz, are sent "on the wire" as gzipped .gz files (gzipped twice -- so the HTTP response needs to be gunzipped twice) to be parsed as XML correctly.

Scrapy does not handle this case, hence the exception printed out.

Here's a basic sitemap spider that tries to double-gunzip responses:

```
from scrapy.utils.gz import gunzip
import scrapy


class CurrentHarvestSpider(scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider):
    name = "newegg"
    allowed_domains = ["newegg.com"]
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('parsing %r' % response.url)

    def _get_sitemap_body(self, response):
        body = super(CurrentHarvestSpider, self)._get_sitemap_body(response)
        self.logger.debug("body[:32]: %r" % body[:32])
        try:
            body_unzipped_again = gunzip(body)
            self.logger.debug("body_unzipped_again[:32]: %r" % body_unzipped_again[:100])
            return body_unzipped_again
        except:
            pass
        return body
```

And this the logs showing that newegg's .xml.gz sitemaps indeed need gunzipping twice:

```
$ scrapy runspider spider.py 
2016-11-09 13:10:56 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-11-09 13:10:56 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-09 13:10:56 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-09 13:10:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-11-09 13:10:57 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml> (referer: None)
2016-11-09 13:10:57 [newegg] DEBUG: body[:32]: '\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding='
2016-11-09 13:10:57 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.newegg.com/Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_store01.xml.gz> (referer: http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml)
2016-11-09 13:10:57 [newegg] DEBUG: body[:32]: '\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xda\xef\x1eX\x00\x0bnewegg_sitemap_store01'
2016-11-09 13:10:57 [newegg] DEBUG: body_unzipped_again[:32]: '\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"'
2016-11-09 13:10:57 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.newegg.com/Hubs/SubCategory/ID-26> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2016-11-09 13:10:59 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.newegg.com/Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_product15.xml.gz> (referer: http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml)
2016-11-09 13:10:59 [newegg] DEBUG: body[:32]: '\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xe3\xfa\x1eX\x00\x0bnewegg_sitemap_product'
2016-11-09 13:10:59 [newegg] DEBUG: body_unzipped_again[:32]: '\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"'
(...)
2016-11-09 13:11:02 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA04Y0766512> (referer: http://www.newegg.com/Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_product15.xml.gz)
(...)
2016-11-09 13:11:02 [newegg] INFO: parsing 'http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA04Y0766512'
(...)
```

Comment: Interesting. But what does gunzipping twice have to do with functions not being called? Does it fail somewhere? Where exactly?  Shouldn't it still call a callback?  Or do something? I don't understand, did it silently fail? That'd be ironic as I feel its too loud; hence why I was attempting to log debug output manually. I can't handle sifting through and filtering the giant dump of unnecessary crap printing to stdout.  It makes my eyes bleed. Nor can I be bothered with screwing around with the poorly documented and convoluted logger module.  I tried it, took too long. Scrapy needs some work.

Comment: See my updated answer. To me, when I ran your spider, scrapy was pretty vocal that there was an error. I don't know what you mean by _"I can't handle sifting through and filtering the giant dump of unnecessary crap printing to stdout."_ . If it's scrapy logs, that "crap" actually showed there was a problem. If it's something else, you don't need to be disparaging to make your point. _"Scrapy needs some work"_: that's for sure, it needs the community of users to throw at it their different use-cases so the code can be improved. Thanks for reporting. You can also help fix the bug if you wish.

Comment: It's really more of a me problem, not a scrapy problem.  You've got an excerpt up there.  I can read that.  But it's tiny compared to the rest of the cluttered output.  For me it's like finding a need in a haystack, I frequently re-read lines, lose my place, and get overwhelmed with all these lines.  I'd be lucky to find what you found in the console output.

My complaint is that typically when your program encounters say a runtime error, the program halts execution and returns the error, right? Well scrapy does not. It craps out a needle into a haystack and keeps going instead.

Comment: I take that all back.  I wasn't very thorough.  I had a slightly modified version of this code and it wasn't throwing errors or calling callbacks  yesterday (probably for the reasons you outlined in your answer).   I tweaked the code here but failed to test to see if I could reproduce the issue, and now the tweaked code is throwing errors that I can read just fine.  Sorry scrapy, didn't mean to disparage you.

Comment: Oh and thank you for your help and expanding on the answer.  It's proving to be very helpful and things are making a lot more sense.